# Clocked Turing Machine in Undecidability proofs

Tags: computability, turing-machines, decidability

If we are dealing with the following reduction:
$$\overline{K} \leq \{ p ∣ \forall y: M_p(y) \downarrow \} $$
one of the possible definitions for $M_p[x](y)$ is the following:

```
input y
{
  if (not mxxstopsininputsteps) 
        accept;
  else 
      infiniteloop;
}
```

But I cannot seem to wrap my head around the fact that we are just testing if $M_x(x)$ halts after $y$ steps (mxxstopswininputsteps). I have seen this method of construction of the mapping function in other more theoretical undecidability proofs (such as here: [https://www.cs.rice.edu/~nakhleh/COMP481/final_review_sp06_sol.pdf](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Enakhleh/COMP481/final_review_sp06_sol.pdf)) and I just do not understand how testing if it halts after $t$ steps is enough for concluding that $x \in \overline{K}$.